# Take current item to workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I want to write a workflow for sharepoint 2013 list in visual studio 2012.
When user adds a new `SPListItem` to `SPList` -> starting my workflow. How to take this `SPListItem` to workflow and reuse it?

Answer (score 1):

[Try this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn584771.aspx)

Hope this link will help. Also you can find various tutorial on google.